# iterating through ksvm and pulling coefficients

Tags: r, svm

I'm trying to iterate and pass through different values of C in a SVM model and pull the coefficients. I'm using the ksvm library from R, and the credit card dataset from http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/credit+approval.

```r
library(kernlab)

ccdata = read.table("credit_card_data.txt")
c_val = c(.001,01,1,100,10000,1000000)
svm_models = list()

for (item in 1:length(c_val))
{
  svm_models[item] = ksvm(as.matrix(ccdata[,1:10]), as.factor(ccdata[,11]),type="C-svc",kernel="vanilladot",C=c_val[item],scaled=TRUE)
  a <- colSums(svm_models[item]@xmatrix[[1]] * svm_models[item]@coef[[1]])
  a0 <- -svm_models[[item]]@b
  pred <- predict(svm_models[item], ccdata[,1:10])
  }
```

I'm getting the following error -

> for ( item in 1:length(c_val))
>   + {
>   +   print(item)
>   +   svm_models = ksvm(as.matrix(ccdata[,1:10]), as.factor(ccdata[,11]),type="C-svc",kernel="vanilladot",C=c_val[item],scaled=TRUE)
>   +   a <- colSums(svm_models[item]@xmatrix[[1]] * svm_models[item]@coef[[1]])
>   +   a0 <- -svm_models[[item]]@b
>   +   pred <- predict(svm_models[item], ccdata[,1:10])
>   +   }
>   [1] 1
>    Setting default kernel parameters
>   Error in svm_models[item] : object of type 'S4' is not subsettable

Comment: You can check the `str` of the model  with a `print` statement within the loop

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for taking a look at it. Ideally, what i'm trying to do is iterate and create a svm model with different cost estimates, and pull the coefficients out to a variable, along with the accuracy. I'm pretty new to R, so i'm trying a bit.